# Error with overlapping memory with inplace operation on a Tensor using the *= operator

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am trying to run this code that generates 2 tensors an then do the `*=` operation:

```
num_agents_alive, agent_mask = self.get_agent_mask(batch_size, info)

comm_action = torch.tensor(info['comm_action'])
comm_action_mask = comm_action.repeat(batch_size, n, n).unsqueeze(-1)
            
# action 1 is talk, 0 is silent i.e. act as dead for comm purposes.
agent_mask *= comm_action_mask.double()
```

The tensors involved are `comm_action_mask` of Size (1,4,16,1) and `agent_mask` of Size (1,4,4,1). The `agent_mask *= comm_action_mask.double()` line produces the error:

<sup>*** RuntimeError: unsupported operation: more than one element of the written-to tensor refers to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.</sup>
This is either from the `*=` operator or due to `repeat`.

I tried to use clone `agent_mask = agent_mask.clone() * comm_action_mask.double()` which has an issue with the dimensions of the tensors. I am a bit confused as to why this doesn't work if someone can explain and a possible solution. Thanks.